# UICollectionViewController UIEdgeInsets wired behaviour

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uiedgeinsets

Actually, Working fine for default System .

> Total dataSource count is 7 items

When I just changed to the `UIEdgeInsets` to ***left*** for `insetForSectionAtIndex`.
`UIEdgeInsets` works fine but Visible area of the CollectionView equally centralised,  Missing item at rightSide corner ..

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,192, 0, 0);
}
```

[image]

> BUT, when I changed it to the Right works fine for right alignment,

```
 - (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0, 0,192);
    }
```

[image]

I hope that this is the simple question. but I couldn't get the solution .

Even I've been played with the `UIContentInsets` && `Spacing` as well, but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just played around with the `UICollectionViewController`, but no luck . So simply choose a **alternative way** for it by use of the `UIViewController` with the subView of `UICollectionView`